# What is meant for and why we use these "SAML", "SSO", "SAML SSO", "OPENID", "OPENID-CONNECT"

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity server.

My task user can login with any type using Facebook, Goolge, SAML, OPENID, other Application and using WSO2 Identity Server.

But am confusing "SAML", "SSO", "SAML SSO", "OPENID", "OPENID-CONNECT".

Some where using Facebook authentication using SAML.

Some where using Google authentication using OPENID.

What is means and which condition i should use these "SAML", "SSO", "SAML SSO", "OPENID", "OPENID-CONNECT".

Suggest me any sample project which allow me login either Facebook, Google, SAML, OPENID, Other APPLICATION or WSO2 Identity server

Answer (score 0):

"SAML SSO", "OPENID", "OPENID-CONNECT" are the Authentication Protocols. The choice of these protocols are depending on the Identity provider you have planned to use. If you need to use google then you need to use OPENID. Likewise.

WSO2 IS have connectors for all these popular Identity Providers including [google](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Google) and [facebook](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Facebook).

You can refer to WSO2 IS [quick start guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Quick+Start+Guide#test3) and sample-is [repo](https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/sso-samples) for sample projects

Comment: How can i used SAML, OPENID-CONNECT, FACEBOOK, GOOGLE and WSO2 identity server LOCAL AUTHENTICATION Simultaneously as a identity provider.

Comment: Can u explain more on this